# Interest rate question

Tags: loans, interest-rate, interest, compound-interest

I'm having a little trouble figuring this out. Suppose I took out a loan with the following terms:

Loan Amount: 1,000
Interest Rate (APR): 10%
Compound Frequency: Monthly (12 compounding periods)
Number of Payments: 12
Number of Years: 1.0

Compound loan total: **1,104.71**
Monthly Payment: 87.92
Expected Loan Cost (monthly payment * num payments): 87.92*12 = **1,055.04**

Plugging in the above numbers in [an online payment calculator](http://www.bankrate.com/calculators/auto/auto-loan-calculator.aspx) results in the same monthly payment of $87.92, so now I'm confused: why is the final amount different?

I tried [another compound interest calculator online](http://www.thecalculatorsite.com/finance/calculators/compoundinterestcalculator.php) and I got the same result: $1,055.04

The compound loan total seems correct: if I'm getting charged 10% per year, at the end of a 1 year loan I should have paid 10% + compound interest which adds up to $1,104.71. The actual interest rate will be about 5.5% if I'm making monthly payments of $87.92. What am I missing here?

**Update:**
[This compound interest calculator](http://ncalculators.com/interest/monthly-interest-calculator.htm) results in the $1,104.71.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each monthly payment you make reduces your principal. So the loan interest calculated every month is different. On average, you have approximately half of the original principal every months - hence the $54 interest when you have 10% APR.

The compound interest calculator calculates the interest accumulated, but it doesn't take into the account the reduction of principal because of the monthly payments. You should use the [amortization calculator](http://ncalculators.com/loan/amortization-calculator.htm) for that, and that would give you the total of $1054.99 (depending on rounding etc, its close to the $1055.04 you got).

Comment: I'm programming my own calculator and depending on the precision you get $1054.99, if I calculate things by hand it's $1055.04. Thanks for the rest of the info tho, very useful.

Comment: @Lirik so you're just seeding links to your site?

Comment: No, none of those links are to any of my sites. Those are just some sites that I picked up when googling for online calculators while I was trying to cross-verify the results of my application.

Answer (score 5):

The *number of payments* is the source of confusion here.

The interest that's typically charged in a monthly-payment scenario is on the principal remaining after each payment.  With each monthly payment, the principal balance owing is reduced.  So, each subsequent month, the amount of interest charged *decreases* in line with the principal.

You'd only pay $104.71 total interest if the $1000 loan was outstanding for the entire year.  This kind of loan would be one with a single "balloon payment" due at the end of the loan term, not where the payments are spread out over the life of the loan.

In a situation with 12 monthly payments and the loan paid off by the final payment, you are borrowing – on average – a bit over half of that amount over the course of the year.  Hence why the interest is ~$55 as opposed to ~$100+.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some step-by-step calculations so you can see fairly clearly what's going on:-

The [effective annual interest rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation) is given by

```
ear = (1 + i/n)^n - 1
```

where `i` is the nominal interest rate and `n` is the number of compounding periods.

```
ear = (1 + 0.1/12)^12 - 1 = 0.104713 = 10.4713 %
```

The [monthly rate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_interest_rate#Monthly_compounding) is

```
r = (ear + 1)^(1/n) - 1 = 0.00833333 = 0.833333 %
```

The [monthly repayment](http://www.financeformulas.net/Loan_Payment_Formula.html) is given by the formula

```
p = r*pv/(1 - (1 + r)^-n)
```

where `pv` is the present value of the loan

```
p = 0.00833333*1000/(1 - (1 + 0.00833333)^-12) = 87.9159
```

This gives a total repayment of `p*12 = 1054.99`

You expected the loan to cost `(1 + ear)*pv = (1 + 0.104713)*1000 = 1104.71` but the repayments progressively reduce the amount owed so the total repayment is only 1054.99.